# SQL Server Management Studio always encrypt connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In the connections dialog of Management Studio there is an option to encrypt the connection so that you can force the connection to the remote server to be encrypted.

Is there a way that I can make every connection I make in Management Studio to be encrypted - or in other words, make that box permanently ticked?

NOTE: I do not have control of the SQL Server instances I am connecting to, so I cannot enforce encryption at the server end.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use registered servers (either locally stored or in a Central Management Server), you can set that property in that connection. Then when you use that stored connection, it'll be encrypted.